# Dice roll in C♯

Tags: c#

I'm deigning a windows program that allows the user to pick a dice and then show possible outcomes if rolled.

At this point, I can only get possibler outcomes out of 50 no matter what dice is selected. I believe it has to do with an issue in the public RollDice() but cannot be sure.
I am using two classes called FormDice.cs and RollDice.cs

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace 
{
public partial class FormDice : Form
{
    public FormDice()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        sixRadioButton.Checked = true;


    }
    //declare variables
    int sides;
    int answer;


    //assign clear button
    private void clearButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        twoRadioButton.Checked = false;
        sixRadioButton.Checked = true;
        tenRadioButton.Checked = false;
        fiftyRadioButton.Checked = false;

    }


    //assign event to roll button
    private void rollButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        //if statements check which number checked
        if (twoRadioButton.Checked)
        {

            sides = 2;
            RollDice rolldice = new RollDice();
            answer = rolldice.Roll();
        }
        else if (sixRadioButton.Checked)
        {

            sides = 6;
            RollDice rolldice = new RollDice();
            answer = rolldice.Roll();
        }

        else if (tenRadioButton.Checked)
        {

            sides = 10;
            RollDice rolldice = new RollDice();
            answer = rolldice.Roll();
        }

        else if (fiftyRadioButton.Checked)
        {

            sides = 50;
            RollDice rolldice = new RollDice();
            answer = rolldice.Roll();
        }

        else
        {


            RollDice rolldice = new RollDice();
            answer = rolldice.Roll();

        }
        resultsListBox.Items.Add(answer.ToString());
    }


    //exit program
    private void exitToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }
    //about message box
    private void aboutToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      MessageBox.Show("Dice Magic Version 1.0\nProgrammer: PaulPresutto",            `enter code here`"Dice Magic", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }

    private void twoRadioButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

And my RollDice.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace 
{
class RollDice
{
    //variables
    private numberOfSides;
    private Random randomNumberGenerator = new Random();

    public RollDice()
    {


        numberOfSides = 6;
        numberOfSides = 2;
        numberOfSides = 10;
        numberOfSides = 50;

    }

    //constructor
    public RollDice(int sides)
    {
        numberOfSides = sides;
    }

    public int Roll()
    {
        return randomNumberGenerator.Next(1, numberOfSides + 1);

    }

}
}


    private void resultsListBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }



}
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: here isn't a place to review and fix your code, ask a specific question

Comment: Congratulations for using Unicode U+266F *exactly* where you weren't supposed to :) (hint: if you google for your question with "Dice roll in c#" it doesn't show up, but it does if you remove the '#' symbol).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change all these in the first code snippet:

```
sides = 10;
RollDice rolldice = new RollDice();
```

To call your overloaded ctor that accepts a "sides" value:

```
sides = 10;
RollDice rolldice = new RollDice(sides);
```

Since the default ctor overwrites the same variable multiple times, the value of `numberOfSides` is always 50.

```
public RollDice()
{
    numberOfSides = 6;
    numberOfSides = 2;
    numberOfSides = 10;
    numberOfSides = 50;  // last value wins out - you'll want to fix this
}
```

Comment: Good response.  Probably want to set a default of 0 or -1 for numberOfsides in the parameterless constructor.

Comment: This seems to fix my issue. Thank you for the insight!

Answer (score 3):

You're assigning the number of sides to 6, then 2, then 10, then 50 in your `RollDice` constructor. So it always ends up being 50.

You already have a constructor that lets you pass in the number of sides. Try using it. For example:

```
else if (fiftyRadioButton.Checked)
{
    RollDice rolldice = new RollDice(50);
}
```